# Is there a way to prevent my website to be viewed over the webView of mobile apps?

Tags: clickjacking, webview

I have noticed that some mobile app utilizes webview to display and process information.  For instance, this mobile app asks username/password as part of its registration process, then creates a user on my website using webView behind an activity window.  Then, automatically login the user on its webView and display the content of my website.

Old days, the clickjacking issue was a popular topic using iframe.  Similar to clickjacking issue, is there a way to prevent from being webViewed?

Comment: The question is related to a pure technique of web application development and has nothing to do with information security. I suggest to close it or to move it to SO.

Comment: @mentallurg, I somehow agree with your comment, but this brings some security and privacy concerns.  Users are being created without knowing our privacy and other statements.  Also, for that same reason, personal and financial information is being submitted to us without users' consent.  From the server side, all the legit buttons and checkmarx are there.  But it's done by the app, not by the user.

Comment: What you are saying here differs from what you are asking in the question. 1) If you don't like that some app uses your web application, you can employ lawyers, then place your question at Law SE. 2) If you are worried about confirmations and consents, use other registration ways, e.g. per email or per SMS. 3) But your question sounds completely different: How to technically prevent embedding into a web view. That's why SO is the most suitable site for this. If you are not interested in an answer, then delete your question.

Comment: Understood.. I guess I was looking for a technical way of preventing it from being embedded in webview.  Thanks for moving to SO. @mentallurg